# What's the range for the close range and long range bowgun mods?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

The bowgun has a variety of mods for it, including a close range and long range damage mod. They each increase damage at different ranges, but the game doesn't get any more precise than just "close range" and "long range".

What's the range for each mod to take effect? Are there any other differences between the mods (i.e. does one give a larger boost)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done  some experimenting in the Training room using three **Iron Assault I** Heavy Bowgun (one with close range mod, one with long range mod, and one with no mods) to determine how the Close Range and Long Range Bowguns mods work.

The **Close Range Mod** increases damage if you're within just shy of 1 roll of the target, and the **Long Rang Mod** increases damage if you're just a little more than 2 rolls away from the target (you'll be outside the range of Normal Shot). Both shots seems to give the same damage boost, and appears to work on any shot which makes use of critical distance (i.e. shots like Slicing and Cluster don't benefit from the mod) *including*  the the **Wyvernheart** special ammo (Wyvernsnipe doesn't appear to benefit from the mods).

So what this means is that if you're primarily going to be using Normal and Spread shots then you should use the **Close Range Mod**, and if you're going to be using a lot of Pierce shots then use the **Long Range Mod**.

Comment: So would it be a stretch to say these mods affect the damage boost from critical distance? Wyvernsnipe most likely has no critical distance modifiers.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Not exactly, because an ammo type can be within critical distance and not get the bonus.

Comment: Sorry for necromancing an old answer, but how does it interact with Power Barrel and Long Barrel, new mods in Iceborne? They affect projectiles' speed such that the effective distances become much shorter for Power Barrel, and longer for Long Barrel.